# php - How to generate a list of YouTube videos from a list of random YouTube video IDs?

Tags: php, api, youtube

I am looking to create a small PHP website of a collection of random YouTube videos.

I know I will be utilizing the YouTube API.  I've found tutorials on how to use the YouTube API to make search queries, and grab a particular playlist from YouTube, but not necessarily any way to generate a list on my website of video titles, thumbnails and short descriptions from a simple PHP array of random YouTube video IDs.

ie:

```
  $video_ids = [XXXXXXXXX,XXXXXXXXX,XXXXXXXXX,XXXXXXXXX];
```

Is there a special YouTube API function or method I can call in the API that does exactly this?  Basically I just want to throw a list of random video IDs at the YouTube API and have the API return information for each of those video IDs in the list.

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do a PHP curl to:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id={VIDEO ID}&key={API KEY}&fields=items(id,snippet(channelId,title,categoryId),statistics)&part=snippet,statistics

That should return JSON with the info for that video

Comment: Thanks!! Your answer pointed me in the right direction.  After I created an API key from Google Developers Console, I was able to use the YouTube API exactly the way I needed to.  For anyone looking to do exactly what I'm trying to do (generate a list of YT videos with title, thumbnail and description, here is the URL I used: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id={comma separated video IDs}&key={API KEY}